# How should I deal with 3rd party content in my portfolio items?

Tags: professionalism, job-search, software-development

I'm writing a project that I want to use in my portfolio as web developer and I'm using a JS 3rd party module in my code. This **module covers a lot of different use cases that are not immediately relevant to my project**. I want my code to be as simple and clear as possible and I'm worried that using too much external content would show that I have a tendency of relying on other people's work.

Does it make sense to **adapt the parts of code I need and place that in my own program with a mention to the module and its author**? My hope is that doing so would at least show that I took the time of understanding why that solution worked and learned a lesson from it.

Is it bad practice to provide software that makes extensive use of somewhat obscure plugins instead of presenting its own implementation directly in its source code?

*Note: I don't mean I should rewrite modules that are assumed to be part of the common repertoire, as Lodash or ReactRouter*

Comment: Let's assume they are open-source and there are no legal ramifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's completely normal to use every sort of library in such a project, it's part of your skill set.  **Nothing to mention here.**

Don't overthink your "portfolio" - just as with a CV, folks just **glance** at it, check the box, and move on.

Enjoy!

Comment: EVERYONE uses third party libraries.

Comment: You're TOTALLY correct, @Neo !!